# Use CSS to show only as many inline blocks as fit in a single line with no partial boxes

Tags: html, layout, overflow, css

I have a bunch of boxes all of the same size shown inside a container:

```
<html><head><style>
    .widget {
        background: red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style></head><body>
    <div id=container>
        <div class=widget></div>
        <div class=widget></div>
        <div class=widget></div>
        <div class=widget></div>
        <div class=widget></div>
        <div class=widget></div>
        <div class=widget></div>
        <div class=widget></div>
        <div class=widget></div>
        <div class=widget></div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

[image: boxes wrapping] [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnjzuj7L/)

I am working on a responsive layout.  I don't want multiple lines of boxes.   I want them all on a single line.   If there are too many to fit, I want to hide any that don't fit.

My first attempt was to prevent wrapping in the container and hide the overflow:

```
#container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However that can clip one of the boxes in half:

[image: boxes clipped] [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnjzuj7L/2/)

If there isn't room to show the entire box, I don't want to show it at all.   How do I achieve that?

Comment: just add text-align:center;

Comment: Centering the text doesn't seem to do anything by itself.  I [tried it on js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnjzuj7L/5/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not to prevent wrapping.   The solution is to allow the boxes to wrap, but to hide any that wrap to the next line.

To implement that, the height of the container needs to be fixed and the overflow needs to be hidden:

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image] [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnjzuj7L/3/)

`text-align: center;` can be added to the container if desired to center all the boxes that fit: [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnjzuj7L/4/)